# MATLAB reads UNICODE CSV with spaces between characters

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, unicode, text-parsing

I am using the `fgetl` command to read a `.csv` file but instead of returning the results I wanted as:

```
"HIST",1,1,27,PWH,"1"
```

it returned with additional space between each character:

```
" H I S T         " , 1 , 1 , 2 7 , P W H , " 1 "
```

I know that I can replace the space with `regexprep`, but my file contains billions of lines so the added expression might consume considerably more time. I had a feeling that this is a unicode issue and someone pointed out the same issue when he used Java and it was related to unicode. I wonder if anyone knows a better way to deal with the problem in MATLAB?

#### Update:

It should be the unicode issue because the `.csv` file is an output from another program, and when I read it using `fgetl` the spaces are added. However, if I save the `.csv` file again using Excel and read the `.csv` file using `fgetl` again, it returns the results I want.

I am not able to provide an example because the `.csv` file is very large and I cannot make a small sample because when I open and save it from Excel, this problem is gone.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], I do not see this behavior in R2015b with the given example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I believe this is not related the use of "fgetl". It should be the unicode issue because the csv file is an output from another program and when I read it using fgetl, the spaces were added. However, if I save the csv file again using excel and read the csv file using fgetl again, it returns the results I wanted. 

I am sorry for not being able to provide an example because the csv file is too large and when I save it in excel, this problem should exist no more.

Comment: In order to create a sample, open the file using some text editor that can handle large files (I think Notepad++ is suitable for most applications, and just copy the first few lines to a separate file)... Then see if the problem still happens and if it does - upload the file somewhere for others to test. Without that, your problem is not really reproducible, and therefore you won't be able to get specific solutions for your problem (but rather, only general ones - like the one I posted).

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of demonstration, let's consider a demo file - `demo.csv`:

```
"GIST",1,6,17,PWH,"1"
"FIST",0,4,72,WPH,"2"
"MIST",3,2,27,WHP,"3"
```

---

You have some options:

- [**`textscan`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) (for any text file with a known structure):

  ```
  fID = fopen('demo.csv');
  C = textscan(fID,'%s%d%d%d%s%s','Delimiter',{',','"'},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
  fclose(fID);
  ```

  Which results in:

  ```
  C = 

  {3x1 cell}    [3x1 int32]    [3x1 int32]    [3x1 int32]    {3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}
  ```
- Import helper + generate script (AKA *overkill is an understatement*):

[image: Screenshot of the import helper in MATLAB R2016a.]

Which results in:

```
%% Import data from text file.
% Script for importing data from the following text file:
%
%    F:\demo.csv
%
% To extend the code to different selected data or a different text file, generate a
% function instead of a script.

% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 2016/04/20 19:51:32

%% Initialize variables.
filename = 'F:\demo.csv';
delimiter = ',';

%% Read columns of data as strings:
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '%q%q%q%q%q%q%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
% This call is based on the structure of the file used to generate this code. If an error
% occurs for a different file, try regenerating the code from the Import Tool.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter,  'ReturnOnError', false);

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Convert the contents of columns containing numeric strings to numbers.
% Replace non-numeric strings with NaN.
raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
  raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[2,3,4,6]
  % Converts strings in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric strings with
  % NaN.
  rawData = dataArray{col};
  for row=1:size(rawData, 1);
    % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and suffixes.
    regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\,]*)+[\.]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\,]*)*[\.]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
    try
      result = regexp(rawData{row}, regexstr, 'names');
      numbers = result.numbers;

      % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
      invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
      if any(numbers==',');
        thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\,\d{3})*\.{0,1}\d*$';
        if isempty(regexp(numbers, thousandsRegExp, 'once'));
          numbers = NaN;
          invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
        end
      end
      % Convert numeric strings to numbers.
      if ~invalidThousandsSeparator;
        numbers = textscan(strrep(numbers, ',', ''), '%f');
        numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
        raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
      end
    catch me
    end
  end
end


%% Split data into numeric and cell columns.
rawNumericColumns = raw(:, [2,3,4,6]);
rawCellColumns = raw(:, [1,5]);


%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
GIST = rawCellColumns(:, 1);
VarName2 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 1));
VarName3 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 2));
VarName4 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 3));
PWH = rawCellColumns(:, 2);
VarName6 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 4));


%% Clear temporary variables
clearvars filename delimiter formatSpec fileID dataArray ans raw col numericData rawData row regexstr result numbers invalidThousandsSeparator thousandsRegExp me rawNumericColumns rawCellColumns;
```

- [**`csvread`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) (for numeric values only; which means it is not applicable here).

Comment: Thanks Dev for the demo! but I think textscan won't save my day as each of the element in cell C still contains spaces

Comment: @Jackson then perhaps you should pre-process your file and delete all spaces from it using [e.g. regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3847569/3372061)..? Also look into the [`Whitespace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#input_argument_namevalue_whitespace) optional input to `textscan`. BTW, you might want to reformulate the question, since it seems to me that the spaces are a property of your input data, and not something "MATLAB adds"...

Comment: Thanks again, @Dev-iL.  Yes, regexprep is what I used. I am running a code like this.:

`tline = fgetl(fid);
str = regexprep(tline,a,'');
temp = textscan(str,formatSpec,'Delimiter',',');`

I was just wondering if there is a function in MatLab that directly deal with the UniCode problem....

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same issue. I opened a `.csv` file using `textscan` and it added 1 whitespace on both side of any character and I also noticed that when opening the variable storing the read data, the font was different than the usual in Matlab.

We managed to solve this issue by opening the '.csv' file into Notepad++ and changed the encoding to UTF-8. It solved the problem.

Hope it helps!